# How to show populated rich view in the pop-up for preview on click action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

I want to show a populated main form in a pop-up (sub window) as preview before proceeding to next view.

I was thinking to do this with Bootstrap modal but it looks like it will not allow me to show my rich view in bootstrap modal.

What is the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a form in a laravel blade template, in which you want the user to confirm details before finally submitting?

You can do this with a bootstrap model, inline the template in the blade file were the form is, When the form submit button is clicked, disable the form submitting by using

```
e.preventDefault()
```

in which then you can load the modal programmatically as follows:

```
$('#modalWindow').modal('show');
```

You can populate the fields in the modal using jquery to select the values from your form to populate your modal.

then continue with your submission by binding a on click event on to the modal and when that is triggered submit your form on the page using

```
$('#form').submit()
```